# Can we create a NugetPackage which can support both .NET Core (or .NET 5+) and .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-5, .net-framework-version

I'm just getting started in NuGet packages creation thing and I know how to create a NuGet package for .NET Framework and .NET Core applications but I'm not sure if there any way of creating the NuGet package where it will support both .NET Core as well as .NET Framework. But I've seen the NuGet packages that works with both .NET Core and Framework.

For example, if I open .nupkg file of NewtonSoft.JSON I see the something like this.

[Newtonsoft.JSON hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOFCe.png)

And yes, currently I'm developing my packages using .NET Framework 4.5, so it supports both. But I want a native support for that package not with the backwards compatibility in my .NET Core applications. Also, I don't want to develop using .NET Standard, because in Newtonsoft.JSON package it looks like they are using the .NET Standard.

Comment: .NET Standard or multi-targeting is the way to make things compatible. Without that, you need to do some preprocessor and build magic to make that happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.NET Standard** is a specification that has multiple implementations including .NET Framework and Core/5/6.

If you want to support **Framework 4.5** in addition to core the most up-to-date version you can target is Standard version 1.1.

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-1

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I'll try this one up.